# Laravel BroadcastServiceProvider - conditional middleware for auth guard according to route request

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I want to implement multiple auth guard for the broadcasting routes.

One specific guard is listening on one specific route and this is the reason why I was thinking to use the path request to define which auth guard should be used.

The implementation below doesn't work. I don't get any error message. No feedback at all. The private channel doesn't work.

If I pass the string 'auth:admin' instead of the $guard variable, it works.

When I dd the attributes from the broadcastmanager, the result seems the same if I pass the string or the variable.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $guard = \Request::path() === 'home' ? 'auth:admin' : 'auth:master';

        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web', $guard]]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply provide multiple guards to the auth middleware so it will know which guard using for authentication:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth:admin, master']]);
```

Comment: 'auth:admin, master' not work, but 'auth:admin,master' work